# parsing json response to C# object using jquery

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, jquery

I have following JSON returned from my WCF service:

```
`{"DoWorkResult":[{"AAID":0,"AreaID":1,"AreaName":"Basement","AssemblyAssessmentID":1,"AssemblyID":493,"AssemblyName":"Handrail (Steel)","AssessmentID":1,"AssessmentName":"University Of WA","AttributesCount":1,"CapitalReplacementUnitCost":623,"CategoryID":7,"CategoryName":"Furniture and Fixtures","CountedUnits":7,"CreatedBy":"Admin","ElementID":37,"ElementName":"Handrails and Balustrades","FacilityID":1,"FacilityName":"Central Chilled Water Plant","FacilityPercentage":"0","IsCompleted":1,"IsHeritage":false,"IsSafetyRisk":false,"Level1Units":0,"Level2Units":0,"Level3Units":0,"Level4Units":0,"Level5Units":7,"MesurementUnit":"Items","PhotosCount":1,"RepairCost":0,"RepairNotes":"","RequiresSpecialist":false,"SiteName":"CRAWLEY","SpaceID":1,"SpaceName":"B01","TasksCount":0}]}
```

My service method is like this

```
[System.ServiceModel.OperationContract]   
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
              BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
              ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
              RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public List<BLL.BLL_AssemblyAssessment> DoWork(string id)   {


       return BLL.BLL_AssemblyAssessment.GetAssessemblyAssessmentByAssemblyAssessmentID(1, 1);

    }
```

and I need data parsed in jquery ajax success. how can i parse it to object of my class:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "MyTestService.svc/DoWork",
            data: '{"id":"3"}',
            processData: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
             alert(data);
            },
            error: function (msg) {
               // $("#errorDiv").text(msg);
               alert(msg);
            }
        });

}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you need ? At first glance, the `data` var in your `success` callback should already be an object (does your `alert(data)` display `[object Object]` ?). What is your precise need ?

Comment: I want to get data and it should be collection of rows of type BLL.BLL_AssemblyAssessment ( which is not datacontract but a simple class) and then i will iterate the rows and display in html

Comment: @LeGEC I get [object object] in alert.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
  alert(JSON.parse(jsonString));
```

Comment: It gives error:  SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
[Break On This Error]  

alert(JSON.parse(data));

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript code, calling the `$.ajax` function with the `dataType: "json"` option lets jQuery take care of the parsing.

The `data` variable in the `success` callback is already a javascript object.

You can access its properties :

```
success: function(data) {
    var html = "",
        rows = data.DoWorkResult,
        lgth = rows.length,
        i, row;
    for ( i=0; i<lgth; i++ ){
        row = rows[i];
        html += "<tr><td>"+row.AAID+"</td><td>"+row.AreaName+"</td></tr>";
        // or whatever
    }

    $("#myTable").html( html );
}
```

From what I understand, the class `BLL.BLL_AssemblyAssessment` is a `C#` class, to be used on the server side, not a `javascript` class on the client side. In javascript, objects don't need a class definition to hold data.

You can output an object to the console to check its structure :

```
success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.DoWorkResult);
    console.log(data.DoWorkResult[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see the problem.

Since you have specified JSON as the datatype, the JSON is parsed in to a javascript object in the success handler. Just iterate over it using $.each:

```
//data.DoWorkResult is an array with one element

$.each(data.DoWorkResult, function(k, v){
    alert(v.AAID); //will alert 0 one time since there is only one object in the
    //array and the value is 0 on the AAID property
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HPHTS/)

Note that I need to parse the JSON in my example, since it isnt automatically done by any ajax method there.